# Eclipse not recognizing project as Gradle Project

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I want to build a project with gradle. I have included build.gradle in my project.
But eclipse is not recognizing it as gradle project and I can't build it. Can anybody give a solution for this.

Comment: It won't be considered a gradle project unless the .project file has the gradle nature declared, such as: `<nature>org.springsource.ide.eclipse.gradle.core.nature</nature>`.

Answer (score 17):

I just had this problem in Spring Tool Suite.

Here's what I did.

1. Right-click on project for context menu.
2. Go to "Configure"
   near the bottom of menu (for me)
3. Select sub-menu option of
   "Convert to Gradle project".
4. Refresh project.

The imported project's `build.gradle` then appeared in the drop-down options of the Gradle view.

Comment: I see "Add gradle nature" as an option but not "convert to gradle" unfortunately, I am on eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0), and it thinks eclipse buildship is installed

Comment: It might be that this answer is a bit old. Eclipse has evolved a lot in the last 4.5 years and I have been absent.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using [the Buildship Eclipse plugin](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) for Gradle integration, you can try to add the following snippet into your build.gradle file:

```
eclipse {
    project.natures 'org.eclipse.buildship.core.gradleprojectnature'
    .....
}
```

Then run "gradle eclipse" to re-generate Eclipse project files and refresh your project in Eclipse.

Comment: I wold make this as best answer :)

Answer (score 8):

In Eclipse Neon you:

```
Right-click on your project --> Configure --> Add Gradle Nature.
```

Your project will automatically refresh and you will see all the dependencies being downloaded by Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse doesn't have native support for Gradle. There's [an eclipse plugin](http://www.gradle.org/tooling) available from SpringSource in order to support Gradle in Eclipse, but the easiest way is to generate the eclipse project from gradle, following [the documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#eclipse_plugin).

Comment: I already installed gradle plugin for eclipse.but yet it's not recognizing it as gradle project.

Comment: What makes you think it should recognize the project as a gradle project? Have you run the import wizard, as documented? http://static.springsource.org/sts/docs/latest/reference/html/gradle/gradle-sts-tutorial.html#import

Comment: Thanks...My problem is solved...Once the project is build the gradle icon is disappeared from the project.So again if i need to build the project i need to delete the project and import it once again....

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, to get eclipse to recognize the Gradle project I added the Gradle nature and then I had to click on `Gradle->Refresh All` then the Gradle icon appeared and all dependencies were resolved.

Clicking on `Enable Dependency Management` before refreshing resulted in "This operation is not enabled" and all the Gradle menu options getting greyed out.